# Python Tkinter button stuck down after press

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I press this tkinter button, and the function bound to it finishes, but the button is stuck down. The rest of the gui is fine, its responsive, everything normal except for the button that is stuck down. I can even press the "stuck down" button again, and the bound function executes and finishes, but the button is still stuck down.
Sometimes the first few times I click the button it works fine and the button comes back up, but then after a few more clicks it will be stuck down. What could be causing this?

Here is the code for the button:

```
bf1=Button(self.canvas,text='F1',fg='tan1')
bf1.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='nwse',columnspan=4)
bf1.bind('<Button-1>',self.f1)
```

Comment: Can you share your piece of code that is causing problem?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't have a button.

Answer (score 1):

I have found what is causing this, it is the fact that I am using the 'bind' function instead of the 'command'.

When I use this, the button sticks if you move the mouse off the button before the callback finishes (you can only realistically do this if you have a lot of work to do in the callback):

```
bf1=Button(self.canvas,text='F1',fg='tan1')
bf1.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='nwse',columnspan=4)
bf1.bind('<Button-1>',self.f1)
```

But if you use the 'command', then there is no problem:

```
bf1=Button(self.canvas,text='F1',fg='tan1',command=self.f1)
bf1.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='nwse',columnspan=4)
```

Is this a bug with tkinter's 'bind'?

Comment: A work-around though is to use tk.after in a lambda inside the 'bind', if you need to use 'bind' and not 'command'.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this and `bf1.config(relief="raised")` did the trick for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34538725)